# radiobuttons and spinners in shared preferences?

Tags: android

I have two RadioButtons for Gender in RadioGroup

> 1)Male
>
> 2)Female

and I want to store it in sharedpreferences and retrieve it when i open it again.

As well as i want to save spinner in sharedpreferences how can i be able to save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Try this way,hope this will help you...

activity_main.xml

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

   <RadioGroup
       android:id="@+id/rdgGender"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/rdbMale"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Male"/>

       <RadioButton
           android:id="@+id/rdbFemale"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Female"/>
       </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    private RadioGroup rdgGender;
    private RadioButton rdbMale;
    private RadioButton rdbFemale;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        rdgGender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rdgGender);
        rdbMale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbMale);
        rdbFemale = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdbFemale);

        rdgGender.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                switch (checkedId){
                    case R.id.rdbMale:
                        editor.putInt("genderValue", R.id.rdbMale);
                        break;
                    case R.id.rdbFemale:
                        editor.putInt("genderValue",R.id.rdbFemale);
                        break;
                }
                editor.commit();
            }
        });


        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
        switch (sharedPreferences.getInt("genderValue",R.id.rdbMale)){
            case R.id.rdbMale:
                rdbMale.setChecked(true);
                break;
            case R.id.rdbFemale:
                rdbFemale.setChecked(true);
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: i am having a little problem here . when i set female. after rerunning  app . radio bydefault goes to male .