# Shared Preferences not persistent after app restart

Tags: android, save, preferences, shared, persistent

I found all answers here and tried all solutions, still my shared prefs are not persistent.

Here's my code:

```
public static void setActivated(boolean activated) {
    SharedPreferences sp = Utils.getContext().getSharedPreferences(
            USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit(); 
    editor.putBoolean(ASD, activated);
    editor.commit();
}

public static boolean isActivated() {
    SharedPreferences sp = Utils.getContext().getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getBoolean(ASD, true); 
}
```

I've tried also:

```
editor.clear();
editor.put ..
editor.commit();
```

I've also tried with

```
editor.apply();
```

I even tried with both .apply() and .commit() and no luck.

Another idea was to try using a different mode for the files:

```
...getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

The problem is that the values saved are not persistent. If I close the app and then re-open it the values are all wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas? I would also mention that the problem is only on some devices, for example HTC One S, Samsung Galaxy S3 (I tested on a different S3 and it worked perfectly).

EDIT: I call the save on a button click listener and I call isActivated when I load the fragment (after onViewCreated()).

Thanks!

Comment: See this one :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23654853/radiobuttons-and-spinners-in-shared-preferences/23655104#23655104

Comment: Having the same problem... I have noticed that the problem only happens if I restart the app while it process is still alive (according to DDMS) - in this case it seems that some separate preference file is being used. If I kill the process in DDMS and restart afterwards - no problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract SharedPreferences.Editor clear()
```

> Added in API level 1 Mark in the editor to remove all values from the
>   preferences. Once commit is called, the only remaining preferences
>   will be any that you have defined in this editor. Note that when
>   committing back to the preferences, the clear is done first,
>   regardless of whether you called clear before or after put methods on
>   this editor.
>
> Returns Returns a reference to the same Editor object, so you can
>   chain put calls together.

In my user preferences class I was getting a null value on some other strings and my code was something like this:

```
SharedPreferences sp = Utils.getContext()
    .getSharedPreferences(USER_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
if (session != null && !"".equals(session)) {
    sessionId = session;
    editor.putString(SESSION, sessionId).commit();
} else {
    sessionId = null;
    editor.clear().commit();
}
```

The `editor.clear()` was resetting all my other commits!

Comment: How does this help? Author said he had tried with and without editor.clear(). I have the same issue also without calling editor.clear() ...

Answer (score 1):

Hi I think it should work. If clearing does not work, you could try the second option as detailed in my solution:

You have 2 options:

1. Get shared preference value during the life-cycle of the activity.
2. Call `.clear` before `.commit`

See my answer:

[Android Persistent Checkable Menu in Custom Widget After Reboot Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36939380/android-persistent-checkable-menu-in-custom-widget-after-reboot-android)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why, but it is working by just putting your prefs code inside the async task:

```
prefss = getSharedPreferences(ACCOUNT_PREFS_NAME, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
new AsyncSave(favNamesList).execute();
```

```
private static class AsyncSave extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
    String favNamesList;

    AsyncSave(String favNamesList) {
        this.favNamesList = favNamesList;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        prefss.edit().putString("favNamesList", strings).apply();
        return null;
    }
}
```